# How to show star rating on the category listing page?

Tags: category, grid, magento-enterprise

I am working on the mobile site and I need to show the product star rating under each product.

The helper calls the template `summary_short.phtml` which has section to show the star rating but for some reason the object carries on information only about the number of reviews on the grid page. The same works fine on the product page.

I also don't want to do the query in the loop to avoid slowing down the platform.

Answer (score 2):

It should be there by default ...

In `default/template/review/helper/summary_short.phtml`

```
<?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <span class="amount"><a href="#" onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href='<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>'; return false;"></a></span>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
    <p class="no-rating"><a href="#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: That didn't help, I have altered List.php, no exception is throwned but the template you have provided doesn't seem to display star rating information.

Comment: I have a similar template but the $this->getRatingSummary() contains string(1) "0" even if there are star ratings

Answer (score 1):

In `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/review/helper/summary.phtml` as alluded to before:

You need to change it to resemble:

```
<div class="ratings">
    <div class="rating-box">
        <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="rating-links">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a>
        <span class="separator">|</span>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Review') ?></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

We're stripping out the conditions to check if there are existing reviews so that it will always show.

Be sure to make a copy of the original and save it with the same path in your own package/theme - do not overwrite the base template.

In your `catalog/product/list.phtml` or where-ever you are calling the review summary, be sure to remove the condition that surrounds `<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true) ?>`
.

From the docs:
`string getReviewsSummaryHtml ( $product, [string $templateType = false], [bool $displayIfNoReviews = false])`